# Minio server behind Nginx throws error 104 connection reset by peer

Tags: nginx, minio

I have an Minio instance setup behind Nginx. Whenever I sync large folders using rclone I get error 104 connection reset by peer error for some reason. I tracked the tcpdump just to make sure it's not Nginx fault and it seems it's not. Minio is sending the connection resets.

tcpdump output from my pc to nginx:

```
12:45:56.037558 IP mypc.lan.50299 > myserver.lan.https: Flags [P.], seq 210758:211258, ack 271369, win 513, length 500
12:45:56.037567 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50299: Flags [.], ack 211258, win 4014, length 0
12:45:56.041378 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50294: Flags [P.], seq 304261:304440, ack 231696, win 6722, length 179
12:45:56.073311 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50297: Flags [P.], seq 315796:315975, ack 250662, win 4042, length 179
12:45:56.092129 IP mypc.lan.50297 > myserver.lan.https: Flags [P.], seq 250662:251204, ack 315975, win 513, length 542
12:45:56.092148 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50297: Flags [.], ack 251204, win 4052, length 0
12:45:56.097786 IP mypc.lan.50294 > myserver.lan.https: Flags [.], ack 304440, win 511, length 0
12:45:56.113142 IP mypc.lan.50294 > myserver.lan.https: Flags [P.], seq 231696:232196, ack 304440, win 511, length 500
12:45:56.113152 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50294: Flags [.], ack 232196, win 6742, length 0
12:45:56.121592 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50293: Flags [P.], seq 354178:354357, ack 282451, win 4629, length 179
12:45:56.174268 IP mypc.lan.50293 > myserver.lan.https: Flags [.], ack 354357, win 513, length 0
12:45:56.179362 IP myserver.lan.https > mypc.lan.50296: Flags [P.], seq 269665:270001, ack 211252, win 3463, length 336
```

and the corresponding tcpdump output on the loopback between nginx and minio:

```
12:45:56.092237 IP localhost.40782 > localhost.cslistener: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686849 ecr 4256686849], length 0
12:45:56.092256 IP localhost.40782 > localhost.cslistener: Flags [P.], seq 1:599, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686849 ecr 4256686849], length 598
12:45:56.092264 IP localhost.cslistener > localhost.40782: Flags [.], ack 599, win 507, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686849 ecr 4256686849], length 0
12:45:56.113223 IP localhost.40786 > localhost.cslistener: Flags [S], seq 1989401545, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 4256686870 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:45:56.113231 IP localhost.cslistener > localhost.40786: Flags [S.], seq 2441514866, ack 1989401546, win 65483, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 4256686870 ecr 4256686870,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:45:56.113237 IP localhost.40786 > localhost.cslistener: Flags [.], ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686870 ecr 4256686870], length 0
12:45:56.113253 IP localhost.40786 > localhost.cslistener: Flags [P.], seq 1:557, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686870 ecr 4256686870], length 556
12:45:56.113256 IP localhost.cslistener > localhost.40786: Flags [.], ack 557, win 508, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686870 ecr 4256686870], length 0
12:45:56.121528 IP localhost.cslistener > localhost.40026: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 557, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686878 ecr 4256686639], length 0
12:45:56.179288 IP localhost.cslistener > localhost.40766: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 653, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 4256686936 ecr 4256686696], length 0
```

However, if I open port 9000 and sync the same large folder directly still using rclone I don't get that error at all. Here is the tcpdump output with no errors occurring:

```
12:44:00.253537 IP myserver.lan.cslistenedomacica.r > mypc.lan.49493: Flags [P.], seq 993647:994206, ack 681899, win 9686, length 559
12:44:00.253622 IP mypc.lan.49496 > myserver.lan.cslistener: Flags [P.], seq 530108:530599, ack 991128, win 513, length 491
12:44:00.254002 IP myserver.lan.cslistener > mypc.lan.49488: Flags [P.], seq 1007299:1007860, ack 690855, win 9674, length 561
12:44:00.254018 IP myserver.lan.cslistener > mypc.lan.49496: Flags [P.], seq 991128:991690, ack 530599, win 9662, length 562
12:44:00.254031 IP myserver.lan.cslistener > mypc.lan.49487: Flags [P.], seq 1039391:1039932, ack 653371, win 9709, length 541
```

I don't understand what is different between the two processes.

I am also adding the nginx site config if anyone can spot any issues here maybe:

```
server {
  server_name something;

  set $test 0;
  if ( $host != "something" ) {
    set $test 1;
  }
  if ( $host != "something" ) {
    set $test 1$test;
  }
  if ( $test = 11 ) {
    return 444;
  }

  # Allow special characters in headers
  ignore_invalid_headers off;
  # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
  # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
  client_max_body_size 0;
  # Disable buffering
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_request_buffering off;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
  }

  location /ui/ {
    rewrite ^/ui/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    # This is necessary to pass the correct IP to be hashed
    real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300;

    # To support websockets in MinIO versions released after January 2023
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    chunked_transfer_encoding off;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9091;

  }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/something/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/something/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_verify_depth 2;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt;

}

server {
    if ($host =something) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = something) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name something;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Comment: please share the text output not as picture. paste plain logs as text

Comment: added the outputs as text. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I think you should use `proxy_read_timeout` and `proxy_send_timeout` and set different time instead of default.

Comment: Tried adding the two timeouts with different values but i still got the same result...